# MySQL table creation failed - I get error #1005

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I create a database for E-commerce.

I have one thing doing it wrong and I don't know why ... apparently one of my tables (succursaleProduit) cannot be created.

Error --> `#1005 - Can't create table 'ordidepot.succursaleproduit' (errno: 150)`

Here's the content of my SQL files:

```
        CREATE TABLE Adresse
        (
        idAdresse    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        rue            VARCHAR(30),
        ville        VARCHAR(30),
        codePostal    VARCHAR(7),
        civic        INT(10),
        app            VARCHAR(10),
        CONSTRAINT Adresse_idAdresse_PK PRIMARY KEY (idAdresse)
        );



        CREATE TABLE Client(
        idClient    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idAdresse    INT(10),
        nom            VARCHAR(50),
        prenom        VARCHAR(50),
        email        VARCHAR(50),
        telephone    VARCHAR(50),
        cellullaire    VARCHAR(50),
        motDePasse    VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint Client_idClient_PK Primary Key(idClient),
        Constraint Client_idAdresse Foreign Key(idAdresse) references Adresse(idAdresse)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

        );



        CREATE TABLE Sucursale(
        idSucursale    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idAdresse    INT(10),
        nom            VARCHAR(50),
        email        VARCHAR(50),
        telephone    VARCHAR(50),
        cellullaire    VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint Sucursale_idSucursale_PK Primary Key(idSucursale),
        Constraint Sucursale_idAdresse Foreign Key(idAdresse) references Adresse(idAdresse)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );


        CREATE TABLE Panier(
        idPanier    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idClient    INT(10),
        Constraint Panier_idPanier_PK Primary Key(idPanier),
        Constraint Panier_idClient Foreign Key(idClient) references Client(idClient)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE Produit(
        idProduit        INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        nomProduit        VARCHAR(50),
        description        VARCHAR(100),
        nomFournisseur            VARCHAR(50),
        prixRevient        INT(10),
        prixVente        INT(10),

        nomFichierImage         VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint Produit_idProduit_PK Primary Key(idProduit)
        );

        CREATE TABLE Rabais(
        idRabais    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit    INT(10),
        pourcentage    INT(10),
        dateDebut    Date,
        dateFin        Date,
        Constraint Rabais_idRabais_PK Primary Key(idRabais),
        Constraint Rabais_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE Systeme(
        idSysteme    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit    INT(10),
        Constraint Systeme_idSysteme_PK Primary Key(idSysteme),
        Constraint Systeme_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE Jeux(
        idJeux        INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit    INT(10),
        typeJeux    VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint Jeux_idJeux_PK Primary Key(idJeux),
        Constraint Jeux_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE Pieces(
        idPieces    INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit    INT(10),
        categorie    VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint Pieces_idPieces_PK Primary Key(idPieces),
        Constraint Pieces_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE SystemeComplet(
        idSystemeComplet        INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit            INT(10),
        quantite            INT(10),
        Constraint SystemeComplet_idSystemeComplet_PK Primary Key(idSystemeComplet),
        Constraint SystemeComplet_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE ProgUtilitaire(
        idProgUtilitaire            INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        idProduit                INT(10),
        version                    VARCHAR(50),
        Constraint ProgUtilitaire_idProgUtilitaire_PK Primary Key(idProgUtilitaire),
        Constraint ProgUtilitaire_idProduit Foreign Key(idProduit) references Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );



        CREATE TABLE ClientAdresse
        (
        idClient     INT(10),
        idAdresse     INT(10),
        Constraint ClientAdresse_idClient_FK Foreign Key(idClient) References Client(idClient)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        Constraint ClientAdresse_idAdresse_FK Foreign Key(idAdresse) References Adresse(idAdresse)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE SuccursaleProduit
        (
        idSuccursale         INT(10),
        idProduit         INT(10),
        quantite        INT(10),
        Constraint SuccursaleProduit_idSuccursale_FK Foreign Key(idSuccursale) References Succursale(idSuccursale)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        Constraint SuccursaleProduit_idProduit_FK Foreign Key(idProduit) References Produit(idProduit)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE SCProgU
        (
        idProgUtilitaire     INT(10),
        idSystemeComplet     INT(10),
        Constraint SCProgU_idProgUtilitaire_FK Foreign Key(idProgUtilitaire) References ProgUtilitaire(idProgUtilitaire)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        Constraint SCProgU_idSystemeComplet_FK Foreign Key(idSystemeComplet) References SystemeComplet(idSystemeComplet)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        CREATE TABLE SCPieces
        (
        idPieces        INT(10),
        idSystemeComplet     INT(10),
        Constraint SCPieces_idPieces_FK Foreign Key(idPieces) References Pieces(idPieces)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        Constraint SCPieces_idSystemeComplet_FK Foreign Key(idSystemeComplet) References SystemeComplet(idSystemeComplet)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        );

        INSERT INTO Adresse (rue, ville, codePostal, civic, app) VALUES
        ('asdf', 'montreal', 'H2A7J9', 1245, '1'),
        ('qwe', 'montreal', 'K2A2L9', 15, '5');


        INSERT INTO Sucursale (idAdresse, nom, email, telephone, cellullaire) VALUES
        (1, 'DADA', 'montreal@asd.com', '5145489632', '5145245685');

        INSERT INTO Sucursale (idAdresse, nom, email, telephone, cellullaire) VALUES
        (2, 'DADA', 'montreal@asd.com', '5145489632', '5145245685');

        INSERT INTO Produit(nomProduit,description,nomFournisseur,prixRevient,prixVente,nomFichierImage) VALUES ('PC DE BUREAU','pc de choix','COMPAQ',300,250,'');
        INSERT INTO Produit(nomProduit,description,nomFournisseur,prixRevient,prixVente,nomFichierImage) VALUES ('LAPTOP','LAPTOP de choix','HP',300,250,'');
        INSERT INTO Pieces(idProduit,categorie) VALUES(1,'ordinateur');
        INSERT INTO Pieces(idProduit,categorie) VALUES(2,'ordinateur portable');
```

Comment: this table is a link between `Succursale` AND `Produit`

Comment: Hrmm.  It's working for me.  What version of mysql are you running?

Comment: I'm only on 5.1.  Perhaps something version specific?

Comment: Just that it's not happening on my version.  It works fine.  I'm on 5.1.  I don't see anything wrong with your script.  How are you running it?  Try running it from the command line if you can.

Comment: i try to reintegrate the missing table manually with command line, but the same error reappear

Comment: Also if i try to delete the table Adresse (to reimport all the tables) by : Drop Table Adresse; There's the error : #1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: That's to be expected though, because Client and Sucursale reference it.  You have to drop them first (and maybe some others)

Comment: You can also drop the foreign key constraint from those tables, then drop Adresse.

Comment: @squawknull : Indeed, you're right --> my version was the problem, i downgrade to 5.1.36 (default in WampServer2) and all works THANKS Just post an answer to accept it

Comment: Try removing the foreign key constraints from the succursaleproduit table, and see if you can create it.  Then drop that table, add one of them back, and try to recreate it.  It is likely that one of those constraints is angry.

Comment: Awesome.  Still weird that it breaks.  Maybe there's a bug in 5.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a specific issue in MySQL 5.5.  It does not appear to happen with my version 5.1. Try downgrading to see if that helps.